# Is the quotient space of a homogeneous space induced by a free group action s.t. the quotient map has a right inverse homogeneous?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, group-actions, quotient-spaces

Given is a topological space $X$ and a group $G \leq$ Aut($X$) with the property: for $\lambda \in G$ and $x \in X$, $\lambda(x)=x \Rightarrow \lambda=id_X$, also satisfying that the quotient map $q:X \to X/G$ has a continuous right inverse $s:X/G \to X$.

I want to show that if X is homogeneous (i.e. for all $x,y \in X$ there is $\alpha \in$ Aut($X$) s.t. $\alpha(x)=y$), then X/G is homogeneous as well.

I think I have found a proof for this when $G$ is a normal subgroup of Aut($X$), but it would be nice if it could be shown that this isn't a necessary condition.

Comment: Something is missing, e.g. take $X$ to be the two point space with only one closed point so $\operatorname{Aut}X$ is trivial.

Comment: @user10354138 Then X is just not homogeneous

Comment: This is false even in the manifold context: $X$ could be a surface and $X_G$ could be $[0,1)$ ($G$-action is free but not proper).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't know a lot of the terminology, what do you mean by $X_G$? And does the quotient map have a continuous right inverse? That is really not a trivial condition

Comment: It was a typo, should have been $X/G$. And, yes, there is a right inverse in this example.

Comment: @MoisheKohan could you describe a specific space and group action?

Comment: Yes, later.....

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the quadrant $Q=\{(x,y): x\ge 0, y\ge 0\}\subset {\mathbb R}^2$. Let $Q_0$ denote the complement to $(0,0)$ in $Q$. Next, define the equivalence relation on $Q_0$ by $(x,0)\sim (0, x^{-1})$, $x>0$. Let $M$ denote the quotient space of $Q_0$ by this equivalence relation: The space $M$ is homeomorphic to the open Moebius band. Let $G={\mathbb R}$ with the addition as the group operation. The topological group $G$ acts continuously on $Q_0$:
$$
t\star (x,y)= (e^tx, e^{-t}y). 
$$
This action descends to a continuous $G$-action on $M$. The action is clearly free. One verifies that the quotient space
$W=M/G$ is homeomorphic to $[0,\infty)$. Moreover, take the ray $P=\{(1, y): y\ge 0\}\subset Q_0$ and let $R$ denote the projection of $P$ to $M$. Then the restriction of the $G$-quotient map $\pi: M\to W$ to the ray $R$ is a homeomorphism. (I leave verification of all these properties to you, proofs are straightforward.) The inverse $\pi^{-1}: W\to R\subset M$ also defines a right-inverse to $\pi: M\to W$. Lastly, the space $M$ is topologically homogeneous (since it is a connected manifold), but $W$ is not (since it is a manifold with nonempty boundary).

What goes "wrong" with this example is that the $G$-action on $M$ is free with Hausdorff quotient, but is not proper.

Comment: Thank you, this really did give me some intuition on what is going wrong. My problem is that in the context I wanted to use this, I don't have a topological group acting on $X$, so as far as I understand the group being proper doesn't even make sense. Is there some property on $X$ that would also make this work? I'm sorry if my questions are annoying. I haven't had a formal math education yet, so I don't know some terminology and I'm missing some basic theorems and tricks

Comment: @Li__ON: it is not a group which is proper but it's action on the space. I am sure you have a topological group action, you just do not know it.